# how to get version related info for a version controlled file in CVS

Tags: cvs

first of all, I'm a clearcase guy so it's quite nature that I have the impulse to searching something similar as version tree in CVS as in clearcase. I'm new to CVS, and I don't have much interest to master it. but now the current project I'm involved using CVS as the version control tool, so I'd like to know the answer in the stackoverflow way, quick and efficient.

Comment: What exactly are you after? "version related info" is a bit vague.

Comment: @BurhanAli : it's about tags, branches, ...

Answer (score 0):

`cvs log -h` gives you all the info about tags and branches.